# Не могу распарсить VKList<VKApiPoll.Answer>

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Не могу распарсить `VKApiPoll.Answer answer` - всё время `null`.

```
    VKAttachments att = new VKAttachments();
            att = post.attachments;

            for (VKAttachments.VKApiAttachment attachment : att) {
                Log.d("TAG", "attachment getType " + attachment.getType());
                if (attachment == null) {
                    return;
                }
        if (attachment instanceof VKApiPoll) {
                    final VKApiPoll poll = (VKApiPoll) attachment;
                    VKList<VKApiPoll.Answer> answers = poll.answers;
                    Log.d("TAG", "pool question: " + poll.question);
                    holder.layone2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.pps1.setText(poll.question);
                    for (VKApiPoll.Answer answer : answers){
                        holder.pps2.setText(answer.text.trim());
                    }
                    final String answers_anonymous_textStr = "Всего проголосовало: " + poll.votes + " человек.";
                    holder.pps3.setText(answers_anonymous_textStr);
                }else{
                    holder.layone2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.pps1.setText(null);
                    holder.pps2.setText(null);
                    holder.pps3.setText(null);
                }

================

 VKRequest reqWall = VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, группа, VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1, VKApiConst.COUNT, 100, "text"));
                reqWall.setPreferredLang("ru");
                reqWall.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                        super.onComplete(response);

                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.json;
                        String owner = null;
                        try {
                            owner = (((JSONObject) ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("items")).get(0)).getString("owner_id"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        posts = new VKPostArray();
                        try {
                            posts.parse(response.json);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("groups"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ой VKApiPoll.Answer answer = null...  ошибся

Comment: Вывод вариантов ответов же: answer.text ???

Comment: интересно. вот у вас строка `answers = new VKList<>();` где инициализируется пустая коллекция и дальше вы пытаетесь по ней бегать. Чего еще вы ожидали-то в результате такого действия?

Comment: Как ее з аполнить? Чет я туплю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я конечн не знаю что тут в целом происходит, но вообще  в строке

```
answers = new VKList<>();
```

инициализируется пустая коллекция и дальше вы пытаетесь по ней бегать. Поэтому и `null`

А положить данные видимо нужно

```
answers = poll.answers;
```

Ну или какое там поле должно лежать в `poll` посмотрите.

Comment: Не помогло... все ровно в дебагере size=0;

Comment: @sviter-pro в `poll` у вас что? что-нибудь вообще приходит? может и не приходит вообще ничего?  тот же `attachment` вы приводите к `VKApiPoll` а там может и нет ничего. Посмотрите что в нём

Comment: Все работает и все приходит кроме ответов!!! Статью обновил

Comment: @sviter-pro можете показать то, что приходит в `attachment`?

Comment: обновил статью.

Comment: @sviter-pro эх, я имел в виду сам код response, а не скрин..... хз может там у них теперь в `question` поля лежат... там вон стрелка на скрин у этого пункта есть.

Comment: Обновил.........

Comment: @sviter-pro Ну смотрите. Если выполнять как написано в документации: https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK, то есть подключение `TransportClient transportClient = HttpTransportClient.getInstance(); 
VkApiClient vk = new VkApiClient(transportClient);` и выполнить запрос к открытому методу `GetResponse getResponse = vk.wall().get() 
    .ownerId(-50242541) 
    .count(100) 
    .offset(15) 
    .execute();` то всё приходит. http://s41.radikal.ru/i094/1612/6b/56ecde338685.jpg

Comment: @sviter-pro Соответственно, вы просто где-то не так парсите. Идите от самого корня полученного ответа (от целого json который вы получили) и парсите как полагается. Ответ на заданный вопрос я дал. А вот отладкой вам нужно самому заняться.

Comment: А как перенести getResponse в мой VKRequest??? Это возможно?

Comment: @sviter-pro хз. но пробуйте не через парсинга JSON, а через уже предоставленные методы в SDK...... пример: `Answer answer = getResponse.getItems().get(0).getAttachments().get(1).getPoll().getAnswers().get(0);`

Comment: А какая библиотека под gradle у GetResponse?

Comment: @sviter-pro я не понял о чем вы...... я юзал java SDK ... как всё юзать написано тут https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK..... как с гредла её взять https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-java-sdk .... но вам оно не надо. у вас тоже самое должно быть и в андройде, я уверен в этом

Comment: Не нашол...все облазил..но не нашол